# Active record last insert ID

Tags: php, activerecord

I have a table with an auto_incrementing column that’s set as the primary key. Is it possible to get the number from this column after doing an insert with active record without having to run another query?

```
$payment = new Model\Payment;
$payment->userId = $userId;
$payment->item = $item;
$payment->state = 'I';
```

> $insert_id =

```
$payment->save();
```

Comment: Active record is just a pattern. So the answer depends on implementation details. Usually Model#save() returns primary key, or Model will get one after saving and you will be able to get it with $payment->id

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$payment->save();
$insert_id = $payment->id;
```